# Without using drop, how to take and print alternate lines (odd or even) in a list?

Tags: list, haskell

I have written a working version using drop here:

```
main = do cs <- getContents
          putStr $ unlines $ oddL $ lines cs

oddL :: [a] -> [a]
oddL [] = []
oddL (x:xs) = x : (oddL $ drop 1 xs)
```

but I was wondering if there is a way to do it without drop? Even if it is not as efficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
oddL :: [a] -> [a]
oddL (x:_:xs) = x : oddL xs -- "forget" the even element
oddL [x]      = [x]
oddL  _       = [ ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Hint: replace the `x:xs` pattern with a `[x]` pattern and an `x1 : x2 : xs` pattern.

Comment: Thanks for this! I have figured out a method similar to Zeta's answer, but mine was short of the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You can also reuse [library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) code for this, as in

```
import Data.List.Split
oddL = map head . chunksOf 2
```